# Issue with Twitter Buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm having this sort of issue with the Twitter button on my webpage. In Firefox Developer Edition, the background of my webpage causes the button to render incorrectly.

example:

```
#container
{
    background-color: #f0f1f4
}
```

causes the text within the button to render white.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Broken Twitter Button]

What's up with that?

**EDIT**
This is a bug in Firefox Developer Edition, and does not carry over to the official Firefox release. A bug report has already been filed: [Firefox Bug #1112240](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1112240)

Comment: Does the twitter button have a semi transparent gradient? You need to inspect the element to check it's css.

Comment: What happens if you make the container background colour black for example?

Comment: I didn't see anything where it was using transparencies. I did fiddle with it's CSS, and border-radius, for some odd reason, caused it. So, disabling the border-radius fixed it. Since it's part of Twitter's source that's grabbed through it's iframe however, I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text on Twitter button takes the color of your container, so it is #f0f1f4.

You need to specify in style sheet its own color:

```
a.twitter-share-button {
  color: #333;
}
```

I hope it helps, please read more documentation there:
https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/css

Comment: I'm using AddThis for the buttons, so I have no control over it's CSS. This is only an issue with Firefox Dev Edition. All others work just fine. Looking at other websites with the buttons implemented within Firefox Dev, they all render incorrectly. Not just my website.

Comment: If you are using share this, you can add a custom class and then style it however you want. http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/446558-custom-buttons

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firefox Dev Edition and I have no idea what is the cause.

Comment: It's basically the aurora channel for Firefox, with a new development tools included that's not in the official Firefox release. I'm feeling it's more an issue on Mozilla's side, and I've made a bug report there.